# PHP emailing only populated values

Tags: php, email, for-loop

I have a an online form which lists pitcher information for my child's baseball league.  The form allows for multiple pitchers to be entered (an unknown quantity).  I'm having problems looping through the results to get them emailed to me.

Here's the code from the form (this is for pitcher1 - up to 10 pitchers per form):

```
<tr bgcolor=#cfcfcf>
<td align=center><b>Team</td><td align=center><b>Pitcher Name</td>
<td align=center><b>Age</td><td align=center><b>Pitches</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="pitcherteam1" size="1">
<option>PLEASE SELECT TEAM
<option>Team 1</option>
<option>Team 2</option>
<option>Team 3</option>
</select></td><td>
<input type=text size=50 name="pitcher1"></td>
<td><select name="pitcherage1" size="1">
<option>AGE
<option>8
<option>9
</select></td>
<td><input type="text" size=3 name="pitcherpitches1"></td></tr>
```

Here's what I have in my php email function:

```
$size_array = count($_POST['pitcher[]']);
for ($i=0; $i<$size_array; $i++){ 
$message .= <<<MESSAGE

<tr><td>$_POST['pitcherteam'][$i]</td>
<td><b>$_POST['pitcher'][$i]</td>
<td><b>$_POST['pitcherage'][$i]</b></td>
<td><b>$_POST['pitcherteam'][$i]</b></td></tr> 
MESSAGE;
}
```

I'm hoping to loop through the form and target only rows that have a pitcher input (vs. echoing all 10 rows each time and having blank/bad data in the non-filled in fields).

Comment: There isn't really any MySQL here is there?

Comment: You could check to make sure they are `isset` or check to make sure something was entered `if($_POST['pitcherage'][$i] !== ""){ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your inputs to use the `[]` syntax instead of setting a number:

```
<tr bgcolor=#cfcfcf>
<td align=center><b>Team</td><td align=center><b>Pitcher Name</td>
<td align=center><b>Age</td><td align=center><b>Pitches</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="pitcherteam[]" size="1">
<option>PLEASE SELECT TEAM
<option>Team 1</option>
<option>Team 2</option>
<option>Team 3</option>
</select></td><td>
<input type=text size=50 name="pitcher[]"></td>
<td><select name="pitcherage[]" size="1">
<option>AGE
<option>8
<option>9
</select></td>
<td><input type="text" size=3 name="pitcherpitches[]"></td></tr>
```

Then remove `[]` from the PHP because PHP automatically parses those into a native array. Also have a check so that you ignore the row if the pitcher is blank.

```
$size_array = count($_POST['pitcher']); // <-- notice there's no []
for ($i=0; $i<$size_array; $i++){ 
    if($_POST['pitcher'][$i] != ''){
       $message .= <<<MESSAGE
        <tr><td>{$_POST['pitcherteam'][$i]}</td>
        <td><b>{$_POST['pitcher'][$i]}</td>
        <td><b>{$_POST['pitcherage'][$i]}</b></td>
        <td><b>{$_POST['pitcherteam'][$i]}</b></td></tr>
MESSAGE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that concept!  So - I can just repeat that form code for all 10 entries and php will be able to differentiate? Also - for some reason - when I add php code block to my email form - it's throwing a 500 internal server error.  Is there anything in there I need to declare ahead of time?  It works fine with this section commented out.

Comment: I've fixed that, see my edit. In the heredoc, the variables needed `{}` around them. Also the `MESSAGE;` to close the heredoc must not have any whitespace before it on the same line. And yes, you can just repeat the HTML and PHP will differentiate (this works because they appear one after another in the correct order).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value of $_POST['pitcher'][$i] is set and skip the message if it isn't:

```
if( !isset($_POST['pitcher'][$i]} ) continue;
```

Or, for your code:

```
$size_array = count($_POST['pitcher[]']);
for ($i=0; $i<$size_array; $i++){
  if( !isset($_POST['pitcher'][$i]} ) continue;
  $message .= <<<MESSAGE
     <tr><td>$_POST['pitcherteam'][$i]</td><td><b>$_POST['pitcher'][$i]</td><td><b>$_POST['pitcherage'][$i]</b></td><td><b>$_POST['pitcherteam'][$i]</b></td></tr> 
MESSAGE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick script I wrote from the code you embedded. I looked at your question about an hour ago when there was limited response and since then you seem to have your problem solved.  Instead of tossing this code, I figure I would just offer it in case it helps you or someone else.

test.php::

```
print "<html><head><title>title</title></head><body>";
$size_array = count($_POST['pitcher']); // <-- notice there's no []
for ($i=0; $i<$size_array; $i++){ 
    if($_POST['pitcher'][$i] != ''){
      $team = $_POST['pitcherteam'][$i];
      $pitchername = $_POST['pitchername'][$i];
      $age = $_POST['pitcherage'][$i];
      $pitcherpitches = $_POST['pitcherpitches'][$i];
      if ($pitchername) {
        print "$team, $pitchername, $age, $pitcherpitches<br>";
      }
    }
}

$form_input_row = '<table><tr bgcolor=#cfcfcf><td align=center><b>Team</td><td align=center><b>Pitcher Name</td><td align=center><b>Age</td><td align=center><b>Pitches</td></tr><tr><td><select name="pitcherteam[]" size="1"><option>PLEASE SELECT TEAM<option>Team 1</option><option>Team 2</option><option>Team 3</option></select></td><td><input type=hidden size=50 name="pitcher[]" value="somedata"><input type=text size=50 name="pitchername[]"></td><td><select name="pitcherage[]" size="1"><option>AGE<option>8<option>9</select></td><td><input type="text" size=3 name="pitcherpitches[]"></td></tr></table>';

print "<form method=\"POST\">";
for ($j = 0; $j<6; $j++) {
  print $form_input_row;
}
print "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";
print "</form></body></html>";
```